# How to create an array in assembly for 68hc11?

Tags: arrays, assembly, 68hc11

I need to write a program that will execute from $100, allocate a 200-byte array at $800, and initialize that array with the values 200, 199, … 1.

I need to know how to create a loop that will decrement an array while decrementing the value to be stored in an array.

Any ideas or suggestions? I cannot find alot of example code for this processor.

```
ORG  $100

      LDAA #200
      STAA #$800
      DECA
      BNE
```

Comment: There's no such concept as array in assembly. Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: There are no data structures in assembly, you have to write them yourself. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I cant find examples. I know I need to use branch instructions to mimic a loop.

Comment: Sorry but I think you need to check your assembly course again or read a book/tutorial. This is not the place to learn assembly.

Comment: No but it is a site for answers.

Comment: Right but your question is too broad. Read the FAQ.

Comment: You need to do everything yourself in assembly. The simplest representation of an array is a consecutive sequence of same-size values starting at a certain memory location. That location has a label you put on it (the name of your array - say you call it `foo`). You choose a register to be your "index" and/or another register to be your current array address (which starts at `foo` prior to the start of your loop). See how far that takes you. I agree with @m0skit0 - SO is not a tutorial site. It's not up for opinion. Read the online help for the site. You haven't even said what assembler.

Comment: Ok thats quite helpful. I'm using sim11 buffalo monitor to test  but need to use notepadd ++ and sim11 also.

Comment: Notepad++ works fine for editing assembly source. Any plain text editor will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vreset              equ       $FFFE
RAM                 equ       $800
ROM                 equ       $100

ARRAY_SIZE          equ       200

                    org       RAM

array               rmb       ARRAY_SIZE

                    org       ROM

Start               ldx       #array
                    ldaa      #ARRAY_SIZE
Loop                staa      ,x
                    inx
                    deca
                    bne       Loop

                    bra       *

                    org       Vreset
                    dw        Start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have memory at address $800, simply write and read your data there, using the instructions of 68HC11. You don't need to declare the array in some special way.

There is only one exception - if your CPU runs some operating system, that manages the RAM memory by itself. Then you need to call some OS function in order to allocate needed memory. But this process has nothing to do with assembly programming. Simply read the documentation of your OS (if any).